# LINQ Query for stock and value by FIFO Method

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having trouble with FIFO stock calculation. Here are the table and desired output result.

```
 item  date           time      in_qty  out_qty  in_Price  out_Price
ABC   01-April-2012  00:00:00  200              750.00   
ABC   05-April-2012  00:00:00          100                800.00     
ABC   10-April-2012  00:00:00  50               700.00                      
ABC   16-April-2012  00:00:00  75               800.00
ABC   25-April-2012  00:00:00          175                850.00
XYZ   02-April-2012  00:00:00  150              350.00
XYZ   08-April-2012  00:00:00          120               380.00
XYZ   12-April-2012  00:00:00          80                370.00
XYZ   24-April-2012  00:00:00  80               330.00
XYZ   24-April-2012  00:00:00  90               340.00      
LPQ   26-April-2012  00:00:00  70               240.00
LPQ   27-April-2012  00:00:00  30               230.00
```

I need the value of the inventory for each item in FIFO (First in first out) meaning the first purchased item should be consumed first. The output stock valuation of the above data is.

```
Item    Qty   Value
ABC     50    40000
XYZ     110   40500
LPQ     100   23700
```

Please help me to get the solution in FIFO

Comment: Write SQL first. But I don't think it will be effective without Window functions, which are not available in EF.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you are looking for. However, I think that what you are looking for is something like this:

```
  var items =
            from s in stocks
            group s by s.Item into itemGroup
            select new
            {
                Item = itemGroup.Key,
                Quantity = itemGroup.Sum(qty => qty.InQuantity - qty.OutQuantity),
                Value = itemGroup.Sum(qty => qty.InQuantity * qty.InPrice - qty.OutQuantity * qty.OutPrice)
            };
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Already I tried this. it calculates direct values of IN OUT but I want FIFO calculation for the result.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. Have you tried to add "order by" the date and time?